# If keep resolution = False in gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer

Tags: qgis, gdal, clip, gdalogr

What does it mean if i put keep_resolution = False in gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer?
In the tool itself in QGIS I could choose then a resolution which I want to have for the output, but here via scripting you can juts choose True or false, so either it keeps the reolution from input file or not. But if not, what res. does it take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the *Keep resoltuion* option to `True`, you enable two parameters (according to the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) for `gdalwarp` which is used in this function):

- **-tr** - Sets the output file resolution in target CRS georeferenced units.
- **-tap** - (GDAL >= 1.8.0) (target aligned pixels) align the coordinates of the extent of the output file to the values of **-tr**, such that the aligned extent includes the minimum extent.